# How to display count of registered events in recyclerview in android

Tags: php, android, mysql

`I'm creating an event related app which is having many events in recyclerview coming from MySQL database. I'm having text view for each item in recyclerview, I want to display a particular count of how many users had registered for that event and that count should increment as soon as a user registered it.

I had tried displaying the count of particular events registered in text view and it's displaying for all events except the first event. Don't know why only first event count is showing zero even it is registered many times. So I want help how to write PHP code for that and how to display in text view in android.

[this is count php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDq2I.png)

[java file displaying the count in text view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiYrT.png)

[this is total count operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWAb6.png)

```
 **count function in DbOperation**

public function TotalRecords($eventid){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM econfirm WHERE eventid = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$eventid);
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

Count php file

```
<?php 

require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';

$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(
isset($_POST['eventid'])) 
{
//operate the data further 

$db = new DbOperations(); 

$user = $db->TotalRecords($_POST['eventid']);
$response['error'] = false; 
$response['countid'] = $user['COUNT(id)'];

if($user == 1){
$response['error'] = false; 
$response['message'] = "Success";
}elseif($user == 2){
$response['error'] = true; 
$response['message'] = "error";         
}elseif($user == 0){
$response['error'] = true; 
$response['message'] = "Nodata";                        
}

}else{
$response['error'] = true; 
$response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
}
}else{
$response['error'] = true; 
$response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
}
echo json_encode($response);


**in android getting a count on textview**



total = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);

     StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_COUNT,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);


                           total.setText(jsonObject.getString("countid"));


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("eventid", mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Where is code??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read [How to ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please add the code to the question as text not as images.

Comment: Hey, i pasted all codes pls help me with it. Second code includes both php and java file just they got merged sorry for that.

Comment: @Abbas Thank you and I will go through it.

Comment: Hey, I'm still stuck with this question. Please help me out with this.